# How can i add an record by using id reference of other related table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

I've two entities which are named `Airport` and `Route`. `Route` has two field which named `startPoint` and `endPoint`. Both of them will be id value of `Airport` entity. I'm adding two airport entity, after that, I want to add `Route` by using id values of these airport records. I got an error like that

```
"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of com.finartz.airlines.entity.Airport (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of com.finartz.airlines.entity.Airport (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.finartz.airlines.entity.Route[\"startPoint\"])"
```

these are my entities:

```java
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Builder;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    
    @Data
    @Builder
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "airport")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    public class Airport implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3762352455412752835L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "code")
        private String code;
    
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
    
        @Column(name = "city")
        private String city;
    
        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;
    
        @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;
    
        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    
        @UpdateTimestamp
        @Column(name = "updated_on")
        private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
    }
```

```java
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Builder;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    
    @Data
    @Builder
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "route")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @ApiModel(value = "route")
    public class Route implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8451228328106238822L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_start_point",referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Airport startPoint;
    
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_end_point",referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Airport endPoint;
    
        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    
        @UpdateTimestamp
        @Column(name = "updated_on")
        private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
    
    }
```

And repository of the `Route` is below:

```java
    import com.finartz.airlines.entity.Route;
    import com.finartz.airlines.repository.RouteRepository;
    import com.finartz.airlines.util.HibernateUtil;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Repository
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class RouteRepositoryImpl implements RouteRepository {
    
        public Long add(Route route){
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tx;
            Long routeId;
    
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            routeId = (Long) session.save(route);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
            return routeId;
        }
    }
```

How can I add new `Route` by using request which provided below?

```
    {
        "startPoint":1,
        "endPoint":2
    }
```

Comment: Trying to figure out your question -
You want to be able to instantiate a Route object by providing it only the IDs of startPoint and endPoint.
Correct?

Comment: I've two Airport record and I want to create a Route by using only ID values of these record. @BarHoshen

Answer (score 0):

I would use the session's entity manager to get a reference to an airport from the DB.
Construct using this code whenever you want to create a Route this way:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = session.getEntityManagerFactory();
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Airport startPoint = em .getReference(Airport.class, startPointID);
Airport endPoint = em .getReference(Airport.class, endPointID);
```

Comment: I'm using lombok for creating constructors. You said that I have to create custom constructor am I right?

Comment: If your goal is to create a Route object that holds 2 airports, you need to provide these airports objects in order to create said Route object.
You need to simply get a reference to these objects using the entity manager by providing only their ID.
You can do this whenever you want to. Ideally, you should do this step at the creation of an object so it won't have any null fields.

Comment: In your case - I believe you deliver `add()` with a Route object that has `startPoint=null`  & `endPoint = null`.
You can set these variable inside the `add()` method with the code in my answer. The more sensible thing to do in my opinion would be to delivery the Route object to this method when it already holds this data.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```java
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(route);
tx.commit();
Long id = route.getId();
session.close();
return id;
```

You should not use begin/close transaction. Use Spring Data JPA, it manage transaction session automatically. Your way is not best practices since you use Spring Boot (Let's see https://github.com/donhuvy/library/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/library/controller/BookController.java#L29 very simple and easy).